# Magento 2 - using CSS calc in LESS doesn't appear to work

Tags: magento2

I'm tring to add a gradient shadow to the edges of my pages using css which works using inspector features etc.

However when I add the following code ***"left: -webkit-calc(50% - 769px);"***
to the _extend LESS file in my custom theme, after compilation it changes it to ***"left: -webkit-calc(-719%);"***

No idea where to start with this could it be a bug in the compilation?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This is Less behaviour and not Magento's fault.
Less thinks this is something it needs to calculate for you.
In order to bypass the Less calculation you need to write it like so:

```
left: ~"calc(50% - 769px)";
```

This will then go through Less without being calculated.

If your calculation includes a variable you can use that like so:

```
left: ~"calc(50% - @{your-variable})"
```

There is a second problem that you might run into later.
Magento 2's minification likes to remove the space between - and the preceding number.
In your case that would mean calc(50% - 769px) becomes calc(50% -769px).
This is not recognized by Chrome, Safari or Firefox as valid CSS.

On a sidenote; there is really no reason to use -webkit- unless you need to support the old [android browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)